# ¿Como imprimir Subtotales cada 10 números con Funciones en Lenguaje C?

Tags: c, funciones

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void sumasubtotal();

int main()
{

    int i;
    int suma;

    printf("Metodo de Gauss\n\n");

    suma = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

        suma = suma + i;
    }

    printf("Total es %d", suma);
    sumasubtotal();
}

void sumasubtotal()
{

    int sumasub;
    int i;

    sumasub = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

        sumasub = sumasub + i;
    }

    printf("\n\nSubtotal %d", sumasub);
}
```

Estoy teniendo una duda en este problema porque mi objetivo es imprimir el subtotal cada 10 numeros pero no se me ocurre el procedimiento para hacerlo, solamente para el primero que va desde el 1 hasta el 10.
El enunciado es el siguiente:

> Efectuar un programa que realice la suma 1+2+3...+100 mostrando subtotales cada 10 números sumados. Etiquetar cada subtotal mostrando con la palabra "Subtotal" y el resultado final con "Total".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el subtotal sea lo que se lleva acumulado hasta el momento, basta con imprimir la `suma` cada 10 números. Sabremos que estamos en el décimo número de cada ciclo cuando el número sea múltiplo de 10, y sabremos que un número es múltiplo de 10 cuando su residuo de la división entre 10 sea 0:

```
int suma = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
    suma += i;

    if (!(i % 10))
        printf("Subtotal: %d\n", suma);
}
```